# Best practice for interface

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, interface

I have an object from the database, with assignee and author ID, that is of course referring to a user object. Since I start with a number and end up with a user object, my question is, should the type of the author be something like **number | User**, or should I extend the interface with new properties (**author: User, assignee: User**). Or maybe there is better 3rd solution? I'm relatively new to *OOP*, so I am a bit confused to what is the best practice here and I can't seem to find any answers.

Here is my objects from the database:

```
export interface Ticket {
    id: number;
    status: ETICKET_STATUS_S;
    date: Date;
    subject: string;
    body: string;
    authorId: number;
    type: number;
    category: number;
    assigneeId: number;
    priority: ETICKET_PRIORITY_S;
    severity: ETICKET_SEVERITY_S;
}

 export interface User {
    id: number;
    uid: string;
    type: EUserType_S;
    name: string;
    telephone: string;
    email: string;
    locale: ELOCALE_S;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should the type of the author be something like number | User

Negative: this would require implementing everything in your web application to handle both the case of the number and the case of the object, leading to a lot of development overhead and to a lot of possible bugs due to unnecessary increased complexity.

> should I extend the interface with new properties (author: User, assignee: User)

Yes! This is the correct solution, linking directly to the object. If you have only the User ID number until you fetch more details then you can store it in your object like this:

```
{
    id: 1;
    status: "BOOKED";
    date: "10-05-2018";
    ...
    user: {
        id: 1;
    }
}
```

So your ticket object can be filled with data and the user object, under the ticket object can have only the ID attribute, until the data is fetched.

At this point I'd like to note, without knowing all the business that you want to implement, that in your case it could make more sense to organize your objects like this:

```
export interface Ticket {
    id: number;
    status: ETICKET_STATUS_S;
    ...
}

export interface User {
    id: number;
    ...
    tickets: Ticket[];
}
```

since a user could possibly have many tickets.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's better to separate the ID and the object into two different properties instead of sharing a property with a union type. This is because it removes the need of [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), which is just extra logic that clutters your code and makes it prone to more errors.

A third solution would be to to have for example one interface that is called `DbTicket` that has the raw values from the database, and another interface called `Ticket` that has properties of type `User` instead. Then you just convert when you have the `User` object.